# Oracle SQL Developer - how can I run sql query with parameters

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Can I put the 2 things together and execute without manually having to replace :FIRSTNAME WITH John, etc. I might have many of these parameters in other queries where it would be a pain to type out

Item 1 Given

```
SELECT * FROM Database1
WHERE FIRSTNAME = :FIRSTNAME
AND LASTNAME = :LASTNAME
```

Item 2 Given

```
FIRSTNAME="John", LASTNAME="SMITH"
```

Tried the following but didn't work.

```
FIRSTNAME := 'JOHN';LASTNAME := 'SMITH';
SELECT * FROM Database1
WHERE FIRSTNAME = :FIRSTNAME
AND LASTNAME = :LASTNAME
```

Comment: I don't have sqldeveloper at hand to test, but isn't it asking for parameters value if parameters are present in query? Or I misunderstood your question?

Comment: The question already answered link doesn't seem to help me